# First word hyphenation in parbox with strut

Tags: spacing, boxes, hyphenation, strut

I've a problem with parbox spacing in combination with hyphenation. What I like to achieve is setting parboxes in a tabular-like way as key value pairs. So I have two parboxes with a given width per line. The first problem was the hyphenation of the first word in parbox, that was solved by using `\hspace{0pt}`. Now, when I have multiple lines, each with a key and a value parbox, there's no vertical spacing between.

[image: without strut]

So I tried to overcome this by using a `\strut`. Now, I have the vertical spacing, but the hyphenation of the first word does no longer work.

[image: with strut]

Please see the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\myKey}{MyLongKeyLabel}
\newcommand{\myValue}{ThisIsMyLongValue}

\newcommand{\myKeyValuePair}{%
    \parbox[t]{20mm}{\raggedright%
        \hspace{0pt}\myKey%\strut%
    }%
    \hspace{3mm}%
    \parbox[t]{20mm}{\raggedright%
        \hspace{0pt}\myValue%\strut%
    }\par
}

\begin{document}

    \myKeyValuePair
    \myKeyValuePair
    \myKeyValuePair

\end{document}
```

When uncommenting the `\strut` commands hyphenation will no longer work.

My question is: How can I achieve hyphenation of the first word in a parbox AND have vertical spacing between parboxes in consecutive lines?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: the default hyphenation is not optimal.  suggestion: add to the preamble the line `\hyphenation{My-Long-Key-Label}` so that the breaks come only at "logical" places.

Comment: This is not possible in my case, because the data is generated from a PHP script, but thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word potential to hyphenation in TeX is a sequence of letters (nonzero `\lccode`) started by glue (i.e. `\hskip` or inter-word glue) and ended by something different than box or line. The algorithm is more complicated but the sentence mentioned above is substantial. And `\strut` is box or line. This negates the hyphenation. You need to use this code:

```
    \strut\hskip0pt\relax\myKey\nobreak\hskip0pt\strut
```

and

```
    \strut\hskip0pt\relax\myValue\nobreak\hskip0pt\strut
```

Now, the word is started by `\hskip` and it is eded by `\hskip` too. Both `\strut`s (before and after) are significant because the height of the first strut is used and the depth of the second strut is used too.

Comment: Do you really need `\nobreak` after `\myKey` and `\myValue`?