# How to enable UK English hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation

Why does this MWE not use correct UK English hyphenation? The second line has an influence on `alternate`, but not on `nevertheless`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \fbox{\parbox{8mm}{\hskip0pt alternate}}

    \fbox{\parbox{8mm}{\hskip0pt nevertheless}}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Correct hyphenations are:

BE: never|the|less ([Oxford](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nevertheless))

AE: nev·er·the·less ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nevertheless), [Oxford](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nevertheless))

(**Bonus question**: Why is the first word in my MWE not hyphenated? [Answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232160/30810).)

Some part of my log output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.6.30)  19 JUL 2016 13:13
entering extended mode
**./hindex.tex
(hindex.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 4 language(s) loaded.
```

This output is exactly the same, regardless of whether I use `english` or `UKenglish`.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171084/why-does-usepackagebritishbabel-hyphenate-the-word-alternate-incorrectly

Comment: I see. So the BE hyphenation of `alternate` is (incorrectly) different from the AE hyphenation; and the BE hyphenation of `nevertheless` is (incorrectly) identical to the AE hyphenation. Looks like a duplicate then, the other question's answers answer this question pretty well.